# jQuery autocomplete show hint text in drop down

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Tokenizer:

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

shows a hint "Type in search term" when the user focuses on the input.  Is it possible to do this with jQuery UI's autocomplete? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

I'm using a remote source for my data, but I'm thinking maybe assign a temporary source of length 1 (["Type in search term", ""]) to autocomplete until a search is initiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for: **Update demo** http://jsfiddle.net/vWJdT/ *older => * **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/MQfEL/

I reckon what you are looking for is this: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Hope it fits your cause `:)`

**Script**

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://raw.github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/master/src/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>



  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/styles/token-input.css">




  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/styles/token-input-facebook.css">
```

**Code**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#demo-input-local-custom-formatters").tokenInput([{
                "first_name": "Tats_innit",
                "last_name": "Godfrey",
                "email": "Tats_innit@mit.whatwhatwuthulk.edu",
                "url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png"
            },
            {
                "first_name": "Andre",
                "last_name": "Jackson",
                "email": "andre.jackson@yahoo.com",
                "url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png"
            },
            {
                "first_name": "Andre",
                "last_name": "Jolly",
                "email": "andre.jolly@uol.com.br",
                "url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png"
            },
            {
                "first_name": "Andre",
                "last_name": "Henderson",
                "email": "andre.henderson@globo.com",
                "url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png"
            }
          ], {
              propertyToSearch: "first_name",
              resultsFormatter: function(item){ return "<li>" + "<img src='" + item.url + "' title='" + item.first_name + " " + item.last_name + "' height='25px' width='25px' />" + "<div style='display: inline-block; padding-left: 10px;'><div class='full_name'>" + item.first_name + " " + item.last_name + "</div><div class='email'>" + item.email + "</div></div></li>" },
              tokenFormatter: function(item) { return "<li><p>" + item.first_name + " <b style='color: red'>" + item.last_name + "</b></p></li>" },
          });
        });​
```

**working image**

by the way i ain't godfrey.

[image]

[image: enter code here]

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I am going after.  I'm looking to have the drop down display a hint ("Enter search term...") when the user clicks on the input box to start typing

Comment: @TylerDeWitt hiya man, updated my answer, hope it does the trick for you man! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

What you'll have to do here is update your `source` argument so that you can make the AJAX request yourself. While you're waiting for the AJAX request to come back, you'll pass the widget a "loading" item (like you suggested in your question):

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        // Populate the list with temporary loading item:
        response([loadingItem]);

        $.ajax({
            url: "my_remote_source",
            data: request
        }).success(response).error(function () {
            response([]);
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item.loading) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item.loading) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

The `select` and `focus` event handlers are there to prevent the "loading" item from being clicked or focused. Unfortunately, the loading item disappears when you click it, but this can be fixed pretty easily if it's a big deal.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/WP29E/1/